# Move domain for WordPress site

Tags: domain

Ok, I'm finalising a WordPress site with my my custom theme. The URL is a temporary one provided by the hosting provider, I'll call it www.tempdomain.com for now. In the 'General settings' the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) it says www.tempdomain.com.

When I want to use www.livedomain.com do just replace www.tempdomain.com with www.livedomain.com, logout and login back in with the new URL?

Just so we are clear, I'm not moving servers, just adjusting the URL of the site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For doing that you have to change Site Address in General settings, for the new domain set domain destination to point the directory where wordpress is installed and make sure you change hard coded url to point them to the new domain.

For more info please read [Changing The Site Url >> WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read the above page + do some testing you will hit the WordPress serialized data problem.

The above page does list wp-cli, which I use extensively + likely is overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

Try using the [WordPress Duplicator Backup Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) as it just works + is free + is fast (if you set use mysqldump in settings). The Duplicator code takes care of scanning your code, like wp-cli search-replace, automagically for you.

Also be sure you read the part about GUID in the above referenced link about changing site URL. GUID is confusing.

My rule of thumb is to always set this to what the final live site URL will be, once site goes live. There are many long, grueling articles about this you find searching the Web. Once a site goes live, best to avoid changing GUID.